# Internet Explorer delayed in starting an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My jQuery works very well in Firefox, Chrome and Opera but in Internet Explorer it takes too much time until it *starts*.

I've read many articles and tried to make my code as fast as possible, avoided selections by class, foreach loops and so on, but even when I send a relatively "fast" request it takes so much time until it starts. For example:

```
function getDisturbanceData() {
    $body.addClass("loading");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetAllDisturbances",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "itemsPerPage": itemsPerPage
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            CreateTable(data.d);
            $body.removeClass("loading");
        }
    });
};
```

The above takes around 1 second before `$body.addClass("loading");` starts. The code itself is fast enough, the time between the loading screen appears and the table is created is not longer than in any other browser but the pages kinda freezes until users can see a loading screen. I know the code needs its time until it is finished because I load a heavy amount of data here (in chrome usually 1.4s) thats the reason for the loading screen but I can't explain the time before that.

Additional information: I use ASP.NET framework, and `webshim.polyfill` for Internet Explorer + Firefox support. Next to the default ASP.NET javascript files I only imported `bootstrap.css/js`, `bootstrap-tokenfield.css/js`, `jquery-ui.css` and standart `jquery`

I don't know anything about Internet Explorer or what I can do to speed it up. Can you please try to help me?

When you need additional information it would be kind if you could ask clearly what you want and describe how I can provide them since I never had such a problem.

**Update**
Could the problem be in this part of code that is called once on pageload? It just checks a Session variable in c# backend and returns true or false but it is async

```
function IsUserLogedIn(handleData) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: !1,
    url: "logon.aspx/IsUserLogedIn",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        handleData(data.d);
    }
});
```

}
**Update2**
I know now what slows my page in Internet Explorer down but I'm totally clueless why. These few lines

```
<div id="logon_table">
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Name:"></asp:Label><br />
    <input type="text" ID="txtName" /><br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblpwd" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Passwort:"></asp:Label><br />
    <input type="password" id="txtPassword"/><!--this element is the problem--><br /><br />
    <input type="button" ID="ButtonLogin" Value="Login" autofocus />
    <input type="button" ID="ButtonCancel" Value="Abbrechen"  />
</div>
```

slowing my page down. When I remove them everything works fine, as soon as they are in - even without any css/js attached to these elements **every** interaction is delayed by 1s. When I remove every class and every background operation users still have to wait until they clicked a link. Does anybody know why?

Comment: How is `getDisturbanceData()` called? We need to see all the code between the event being raised and that function call.

Comment: Can you also provide the version of I.E you're using?

Comment: it is called on pageload, this is just an examble because every Ajax request starts delayed. Even when I receive a completely empty ajax request from button click it takes time before it starts

Comment: @KevinCittadini 11.0.9600

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have all your code inside a `$(document).ready()` handler somewhere at the bottom of the page, which means fetching the Ajax resources will not start before the browser notifies that the DOM is fully loaded.

Organize your code like this instead. Outside of `$(document).ready()`:

```
function getDisturbanceData(itemsPerPage) {
    // don't use a POST request to GET data
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetAllDisturbances",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage    // jQuery does the JSON serializing
        }                                 // (also think whether JSON is necessary to
    });                                   // deliver *a single* parameter)
}

$('body').addClass("loading");
var disturbanceData = getDisturbanceData(25);
```

Now, inside of your regular `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
disturbanceData.done(function (data) {
    CreateTable(data.d);
}).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    // show the error somewhere
}).always(function () {
    $('body').removeClass("loading");
});
```

This is a general tip for loading Ajax resources. Start requesting them as soon as possible. Then work with [the promise interface of jQuery Ajax requests](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to handle the results when the document is loaded.

Comment: +1 for jedi example. I'd not put in the head if it'sa consumer public access page, because of the negative impact on google pagespeed. I'd just put it right before the closing `</body>` tag without being wrapped. The libaries will be loaded then and hte javascript parsed. No need for DOM ready, because the dom is already there then. save a few microseconds.

Comment: Fair enough, i've removed the bit about the  `<head>`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Look at the waterfall diagram that shows the timing of your network requests. Compare to how it looks in other browsers. Do all page loads uncached to get a comparable baseline. It's an event issue, not a code speed issue.

Comment: Where do I find that? like I said I dont use Internet Explorer and in my opinion this developer tool has not a great usability

Comment: It has a waterfall diagram on the network tab, just like all the other browsers.

Comment: the time between start and the answer is nearly the same as in other browsers

Comment: Of course, that's not the point. The point is *when* does the request start, not how long it takes to complete.

Comment: I know but like I said I have no idea how to find it out... there is no "time when user interacted" field or something

Comment: Except from doing "best guesses", like I did, this question is impossible to answer with the information you give. Make the minimum sample that reproduces the error so that other people can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I found out what causes the delay, I dont know why but as soon as I use `input type="password"` in my page my IE becomes slow no matter if you interact with it or not. Is there any way to find out why? Even when I remove every js/css file. When I change the type to text everything is smooth as in all other browsers

Comment: Maybe you have a password manager of some sort? Start IE with all add-ons disabled.